# JButton issues -- Java Netbeans NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton, jtextfield

I am attempting to have a simple "Submit" button parse particular information to an I/O. The button is jButton1 and the source textField is jTextField1 (for example).
In Java UI Creation with Netbeans there is a lot of generated uneditable code that is written.  I noticed my ActionListener event is in this generated code;

```
      jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

Next I went ahead and added an ActionPerformed and some other code here:

```
        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    // Declaration of Writer I/O
    File outFile;
    FileWriter aFileWriter;
    PrintWriter aPrintWriter = null;

    // Declaration of String for Output
    String customerNumber = jTextField1.getText(); // Customer Name
    String customerSAddress = jTextField2.getText(); // Customer Street Address
    String customerCAddress = jTextField3.getText(); // Customer City
    String customerStAddress = jTextField4.getText(); // Customer State
    String customerZAddress = jTextField5.getText(); // Customer Zip Code
    String customerTelephone = jTextField9.getText(); // Customer Phone
    String productSelection = jTextField7.getText(); // 1 Desktop, 2 Laptop or 3 All-In-One
    String productQuantity = jTextField8.getText(); // Quantity

    // Creation of outputStr
        String outputStr = "Customer Name: " + customerNumber + ", " +  // CreateString            outputStr
                "Customer Address:" + customerSAddress + " " + customerCAddress +
                " " + customerStAddress + " " + customerZAddress + ", " +
                "Customer Phone Number: " + customerTelephone + ", " +
                "Customer Producton Selection: " + productSelection +  ", " +
                "Product Quantity: " + productQuantity;  // Send to FileWriter after...
        try{

            outFile = new File( "Order Information.txt", "UTF-8");
            aFileWriter = new FileWriter(outFile);
            aPrintWriter = new PrintWriter(aFileWriter);
            aPrintWriter.println(outputStr);

        }  // End try
        catch (IOException error){
            System.out.println("I/O Error, Contact Admin!");
        }  // End Catch
        finally {
            aPrintWriter.close();
        } //End Finally
    }
```

My issue is ... I have no syntax errors, however whenever I press "Submit" in my console I have about 12 different errors ... They are here:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
I/O Error, Contact Admin!
at my.RAConsultUI.RAConsultUI.jButton1ActionPerformed(RAConsultUI.java:345)
at my.RAConsultUI.RAConsultUI.access$900(RAConsultUI.java:14)
at my.RAConsultUI.RAConsultUI$10.actionPerformed(RAConsultUI.java:217)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

It seems I am not using the Java UI syntax correctly, could I have somebody look over my shoulder and possibly point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your syntax is fine, it's your logic that isn't. Find the line that is throwing the NPE and check the variables on that line. At least one is null, and you're trying to dereference it. If you still can't solve the issue, pass the information about the offending line here as an edit to your question.

Comment: 1) `System.out.println("I/O Error, Contact Admin!");` change that `error.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Your program is not finding the file where you're looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"I/O Error, Contact Admin!"` is printed hence `"Order Information.txt"` file were not found, hence `aFileWriter` and it's print wrapped instance `aPrintWriter` is still `null`, and that is why, you are having a `NullPointerException` when you are trying to close it by invoking `close()` function on a `null` instance in finally block:

```
finally
{
   aPrintWriter.close(); // <------ here NPE, isn't it ?
}
```

Comment: NetBeans has this line highlighted for dereferencing possible null pointer ... I believe you are correct, I will have to attempt fix in a few hours ... thanks.

Comment: check out the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for a while to know how to use this site ;)